# Why does MongoDB.Driver Indexes.CreateOne fail to create Index with error "Command createIndexes failed"?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb.driver

When creating a new Collection through code, this call to add a new Index is failing:

```
private static void CreateCollection<T>(string collectionName, CreateIndexModel<T> index)
{
  var database = GetMongoDatabase();

  database.CreateCollection(collectionName);

  var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
  collection.Indexes.CreateOne(index); // Message=Command createIndexes failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the async Collection creation before adding the index:

```
private static async Task CreateCollection<T>(string collectionName, CreateIndexModel<T> index)
{
  var database = GetMongoDatabase();

  await database.CreateCollectionAsync(collectionName);

  var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
  collection.Indexes.CreateOne(index);
}
```

Comment: or just leave out the call to `CreateCollection` since the node will do that implicitly when you create an index.